# Object not visible properly in compositing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend-modes

I have solid object cube and i added image in compositor and made the nodes like the following image, but my object is still blur.

I want my object to be visible clearly inside. Please check where i am doing some mistakes.
[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific? I can't see any blur there, did you mean opacity? Cube should be on top of the image without blending?

Comment: You seem to have rendered the cube without an alpha map. You have to use the alpha map in the *Alpha Over* node as mixing factor.